# What is an efficient way to make a PHP front end to a Django project (that runs through cgi)?

Tags: php, django, performance, cgi

I want to develop a site in Django, to have the convenient ORM, and admin, to ease administration.

However, the only hosting option I have is [running Django through CGI](http://joemaller.com/1467/django-via-cgi-on-shared-hosting/). Therefore, I would also like to make a "read-only" front end in PHP, which will make the experience "normal" for everyday use (i.e only editing [the database] and authentication will be done through Django/admin).

What is an efficient approach (if there is any), to maximize the (overall percieved) performance, especially with regards to authentication across the PHP front end and Django?

Comment: When you say "with regards to authentication across the PHP front end and Django" what do you mean? Do you mean they are both using the same cookie? That the PHP code is approximating the Django auth code? Using the same session state table? (Which would be a bitch, BTW, because the Django session table stores a pickled Python dict.)

Comment: The problem is that every call to Django in the front end, will slow it down. I mean that I would like to avoid writing authentication code in PHP, if that's possible. Could I get away with, for actions which involve editing, just using links to the django backend, and not having the user retype username+password in Django every time he/she visits one of these links (through Django's standard authentication methods)? Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to use Django for the admin and user authentication. Correct?

That should work okay. It's about what I'm doing now, actually, as we're mixing a legacy PHP site (active, used by thousands every day) with new features that use Django.

I have used Django before just for the admin and it works great. I set up the DB tables manually in MySQL, and accessed them like normal through PDO in PHP. I duplicated the schema in a Django model, and set up the admin - it works perfectly.

Authentication is tougher. We're doing that too. I actually found this question because I was looking for others experiences with that!

I *think* the best way to do it is to just store the ID of a logged in user in a cookie when a user signs in through Django. Encrypt the cookie, and you can get the ID and/or other information in PHP. Delete the cookie on sign out, and you should be all set. Unfortunately you won't be able to use Django sessions. You *could* tie this to PHP sessions, though.

Anyhow, I see this question was a while ago. If you solved this for yourself, please check back and let us know how it went!

Comment: Since I began from scratch, I generated the db through Django, and went with h2o-php and adodb in the front end. I avoided the session/authentication problem by keeping it in django only (i.e. no profile functionality in the frontend). Now I have links which point to django in a lightbox iframe, since the user may be redirected to the login page first. Are there simple, more elegant solutions with a bit of jquery magic, for example? :)

Comment: @meastp I found the best solution is to simply store the django session ID in a cookie, then use a PHP function that looks it up. Django sessions are stored as pickled python objects - I found a small program in an SO post to read pickles from PHP . Another option is to change how Django stores the session data to avoid pickling (and thus de-pickling in PHP). I see this as very simple, clean and secure, since you're relying on cookies and your database same as ever.  It allows total interoperability with PHP, though writing to sessions may or may not be easy depending on which method you use.

Comment: @meastp I think to do this, I had to edit some functions in the Django Auth package so I could set a custom cookie... although this was a few months ago so I'm not positive that turned out to be needed in the end.. I'm about to jump back into the project, so we'll see how it goes.